# 質問段階でタグが分からない時、どのタグを使用すればよいか

Tags: 討議, タグ, 質問の仕方

[箇条書きなどの書き方のフォーマット](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/53579/3060)

こういったMarkdownについての質問の場合どのタグを使用するのが適切でしょうか？

追記：
言葉足らずでした
質問段階ではMarkDownだという認識がなかった場合はなにか適切なタグはあるでしょうか？

質問のタイトルも変更しました。

Answer (score 5):

その質問があらかじめ「Markdownに関するもの」と分かっているなら[markdown](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown)や[マークアップ言語](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%83%9e%e3%83%bc%e3%82%af%e3%82%a2%e3%83%83%e3%83%97%e8%a8%80%e8%aa%9e)などを使えばいいのかもしれませんが、件の質問はそもそも「**箇条書きなどのフォーマットが何であるか**」を質問しているので、質問作成時点ではMarkdownと本人が分かっていないし、タグ付けした時点で(ネタバレじゃないですけど)タグそのものが回答になってしまいますよね。

タグは質問を整理するために付けるものですが、当てはまるものが思いつかないからといって無闇に(適当なものを)付けるのは少し違う気がします。

Comment: おっしゃる通り質問を投稿した段階では「Markdownに関するもの」とは分からない状態です。しかし質問を投稿する際に必ずタグを付けろという指示が出るので、次回以降何を使用すればいいのかと悩んでおりました。

Answer (score 4):

質問する際、多くの場合は以下のプロセスでとりあえずのタグが見つかります。

1. 質問文中に出てくる単語のタグが無いか探す
2. 関連技術のタグが無いか探す
3. 今自分がやろうとしていることが属する分野のタグが無いか探す

ただし、日本語版スタック・オーバーフローでは英語のタグと日本語のタグが入り乱れているので、日本語で見つからなくても英語で試すと出てくる場合があることに注意してください。

もし自分がつけたものよりもっと適切なタグがある場合、気づいた人が後から修正してくれます。ですのでとりあえず気にせずに自分が思うタグをつけて頂ければ良いと思っています。

それでも見つからなかった場合は以下のようになります。

- 信用度が充分高い場合、新しくタグを作れるので作る
- そうでない場合、[チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ja.stackoverflow.com)や[メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)で適切なタグを聞く

あまり質問する人がいない分野のタグは往々にして、作られていなかったり、作られたけれども自然消滅したりします。質問分野によっては最もぴったりくるタグが無いことがあるので、ちょっとずれているけれども関連するタグをつけたり、新しいタグを作って欲しいことを伝えて頂けると良さそうです。

今回の具体例の場合、確かに既存のタグでは適切なものが見当たらない気がします（お手数おかけしました）。この場合、上に挙げたように、チャットやメタで聞いていただけるとありがたいです :)

Answer (score 2):

テキストそれ自体に対するアノテーション的なテキストたちは、古くからは[マークアップ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E) と呼ばれてきました。

ですので、正しくタグ付けを行うのならば、それは「マークアップ」というタグになったかと思います。<s>しかし、今今のここのスタックオーバーフローでは、「マークアップ」のタグは存在していないです。(記憶が正しければ、２つ以上の質問と紐づいていないと、そのタグはいずれ消されてしまう)</s> 今今は[[マークアップ言語]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E)のタグを私が作成したので、存在していますが、いずれは削除されてしまう気がしています。

今回の回答であった、 [markdown] はマークアップ言語の一種です。今ここのスタックオーバーフローに存在するタグの中で、一番「マークアップ言語」に近いものはこれになると思います。

ですので、もし似たような質問を行う場合には、いったん[markdown] でタグ付けを行うのが良いのではないか、と思っています。

Comment: 既に[html]や[xml]があるので[markdown]で良いと思います。